# Is it good to have a lot of content in <head> tag in html document?

Tags: html

I have no idea, but does it make difference if we have heavy amount of content in our html document ?

It should not make different, right? Actually, I am trying to load a single page with all text-content in . So, when I click some link, the javascript will write the content for that link rather than reloading another page. 
Actually, the web site is to be built for small company. And data will be just image + text for each document. Is my approach good idea?

Pre-thanks to all contributors.

Comment: What approach? Can you post your code?

Comment: What do you mean by _"does it make [a] difference"_? Of course it does. The site is slower to download, etc. but that is probably not what you wanted to know. The problem is that my crystal ball is currently undetectable...

Comment: <pre><script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(event){
                $("#display").html("<img src='eva.gif' />");
                if (event.target.id == 'idHome'){
                    $("#display").html('<img src="eva.gif" />');
                }                
            }) </pre> So, this is in <head></head>. I don't want to load every page when I click, but write with this script to my display area. Would you let me know whether this is good practice or not? As a beginner, I have to develop good practice :)

Comment: See @David Dorward's answer. You shouldn't do that. Besides, the images need to be downloaded, anyway. Downloading plain text is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it good to have a lot of content in  tag in html document?

You shouldn't have any actual *content* in the head section, and there shouldn't be too much in the way of meta data you could put there.

> Actually, I am trying to load a single page with all text-content in .

This is generally a poor idea. You end up with one very heavy document that takes a while to load, and the visitor might not care about most of it.

> So, when I click some link, the javascript will write the content for that link rather than reloading another page.

Storing the content in JavaScript just makes life difficult. It is complicated to produce, and is unfriendly to search engines, people who want to bookmark or send links to friends, and people who just don't have JS available.

> Actually, the web site is to be built for small company. And data will be just image + text for each document. Is my approach good idea?

Probably not. Discrete documents with normal links between them are almost always better for everyone involved.

Comment: +1! I totally agree. JavaScript should not be required for reading simple text on a page.